# SDL2_image not found

Tags: c++, ubuntu, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-image

I am trying to compile the following code which has the headers:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2_image/SDL_image.h>
```

However after running the following makefile:

```
g++ -std=c++11 src/main.cpp -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal error: SDL2_image/SDL_image.h: No such file or directory
#include <SDL2_image/SDL_image.h>
```

Any suggestions? Not entirely sure about my installation of SDL_image. I am running this on Ubuntu.

Comment: I checked my code and it has #include <SDL/SDL_image.h>.  Try <SDL2/SDL_image.h>, maybe that helps.

Comment: You need to tell us in which directory `SDL_image.h` is installed. Once we know that, we can tell you how to add the relevant compilation option to your makefile

Comment: after running `apt-file search SDL_image.h` I get the following:

    `emscripten: /usr/share/emscripten/system/include/SDL/SDL_image.h`

   `libsdl-image1.2-dev: /usr/include/SDL/SDL_image.h`

    `libsdl2-image-dev: /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_image.h`

Comment: @KarlisOlte Thank you, your suggestion worked! Not sure why exactly (guessing it's referring to the [folder_name]/[file_name]). I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run `apt-file search SDL_image.h`
The result will tell you the location of the include file.

For instance, `/usr/include/SDL2/SDL_image.h` was returned.
So, when you want to include `SDL_image.h`, write everything after the `include/` in between `<` `>`.

Thus, includes should look like the following:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
```

See the question's comments for the original discussion regarding this solution.

Answer (score 18):

This problem can be solved through installing `libsdl2-image-dev` package:

```
apt install libsdl2-image-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

From SDL documentation, it says that add 'lSDL_image' to the end of the compile line.

```
    cc -o myprogram mysource.o `sdl-config --libs` -lSDL_image
```

or

```
    gcc -o myprogram mysource.c `sdl-config --libs` -lSDL_image
```

Here is the reference -> https://www.libsdl.org/projects/docs/SDL_image/SDL_image.html
Section 2.2 Compiling.

So for SDL2, you just need to change 'lSDL_image' to 'lSDL2_image'.

Answer (score 1):

For `Windows + SDL2-2.0.8 + SDL_image-2.0.4 + Codeblocks` you've got the add both `Runtime Binaries` and `Development Libraries` to the compiler and linker. Or else, you'll get the error `SDL2_image not found`, even with having the `dll` in your program's directory, this occurs. Hopefully others find this helpful; I had to figure it out myself. Example: If your resources are separate, you'll be adding the two plus your standard `SDL2` paths to your compiler and linker. Warning: SDL2_image.h has it's headers assuming that the headers are in the same folder as the SDL2 framework. If you get errors about the image header, include the sub-folder `SDL2` from SDL framework in the path and then you should be including `SDL2` in the program as: `include <SDL.h>` rather than `include <SDL2/SDL.h>`.